# Passing command line parameters in bash, detecting content of parameters

Tags: bash, parameter-passing

I'm writing a bash script that will

1. behave differently based on the first argument passed (no prob so far)
2. pass the rest of the arguments to a command (no prob so far)
3. behave differently, if an argument contains a string

It looks like:

```
[[ "${1}" = "-h" || "${1}" = "--help" ]] && echo -e "somehelp"
[[ "${1}" = "echo" ]] && echo ${*:2}
[[ "${1}" = "emerge" ]] && emerge -uDN ${*:2}
some-magic-here
```

Now, if I do

```
myscript emerge -a whatever whatever2 --option
```

it would run

```
emerge -uDN -a whatever whatever2 --option
```

But, in case that "whatever" is a string containing `*`, such as

```
myscript emerge -uDN -a whatever/* whatever2 --option
```

I'd want it to run

```
emerge -uDN -a $(eix -u --only-names whatever/*) whatever2 --option
```

instead. Any tips?

Comment: That is not possible, because Bash expands the `*` before it is even passed to your script. Unless you write `"whatever/*"` in quotes

Comment: It's possible, you just have to quote your input. I.e. `myscript emerge -uDN -a 'whatever/*' whatever2 --option` or turn globbing off.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are going to pass `*` to the script, you must prevent expansion by the shell on the command line. The simplest way is to quote it:

```
myscript emerge -a 'whatever/*' whatever2 --option
```

Since you are already using the `[[` operator, **note:** the following is a **bash only** solution and not portable to sh. To determine if $3 contains a `*` you can use the `=~` operator:

```
[[ "${1}" == "emerge" ]] && {
    [[ "$3" =~ "*" ]] && \
        emerge -uDN $2 $(eix -u --only-names $3) ${*:4} || \
        emerge -uDN ${*:2}
}
```

You can also rewrite the compound commands into nested `if-else` statements if the logic gets a bit murky. Give it a try and let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You mention the command line:

```
myscript emerge -uDN -a whatever/* whatever2 --option
```

The only ways `myscript` will see the `*` in its argument list is if there is no subdirectory `whatever` under the current directory, or it is an empty directory (strictly: if it contains any files, the names all start with `.`), and in either case, you don't have `shopt -s nullglob` set.  If those conditions aren't met, the shell invoking `myscript` will replace the `*` (in)appropriately and `myscript` will not see the `*`.  (Of course, if you quote the argument — `"whatever/*"` or `'whatever/*'`, then `myscript` will also see the `*` metacharacter, regardless of `nullglob` and the presence or absence of a `whatever` subdirectory.)

It is not clear whether the `*` needs to be replaced only when it follows the `-a` option, or if it should be replaced in any argument whatsoever.  I will assume that all arguments need to be replaced; it is not very different if it is only the argument after the `-a` that should be replaced.

Without the code to handle `whatever/*`, the command looks like:

```
[[ "${1}" = "emerge" ]] && exec emerge -uDN "${@:2}" || exit 1
```

Differences:

1. The `exec` is optional but guarantees that nothing after the `emerge` command will be executed (unless the `emerge` command can't be found, in which case the `|| exit 1` ensures nothing else is executed).
2. Use `"$@"` to preserve the arguments as presented to your script.  Without double quotes, there's no difference between `$@` and `$*`.  Inside double quotes, `"$*"` generates a single string, but `"$@"` generates each argument as passed to the script.  The `"${@:2}"` notation does this for the second up to the last argument.

To handle the `*` for any argument, we need to detect the `*`.  This is going to be easiest if we use arrays.

The array `arglist` will contain the arguments to be passed to the `emerge` command. We need to iterate over the arguments to the script, checking for appearances of `*`:

```
arglist=( "-uDN" )
for arg in "${@:2}"
do
    case "$arg" in
    (*\**) arglist+=( $(eix -u --only-names "$arg") );;
    (*)    arglist+=( "$arg" );;
    esac
done
exec emerge "${arglist[@]}"
exit 1
```

Note that this assumes that `eix` will expand metacharacters (`*` to be precise), rather than relying on the shell to do so.  It also assumes, as the question assumes, that there are no spaces in the names generated by `eix`.  If there are any, the `$(…)` notation will split the names at the spaces (or tabs, or newlines, …).

This code would be best handled as the body of the `then` clause in

```
if [[ "${1}" = "emerge" ]]
then
    …
fi
```

This would be clearer than trying to squeeze all that code onto a single line (which could be done, but there is no point in doing so and many points to not doing so).

Answer (score -1):

Here's a clue:

```
#!/bin/sh

x="bbbccc"     # Put different strings in here, and see what happens

case "$x" in
*\**)
    echo "Yes"
    ;;
    *)
    echo "No"
    ;;
esac
```